# CometD & empAPI Issues when subscribing to Platform Events

Tags: platform-event, cometd

As we are using Cometd and platform Events to get the communication happen between Asynchronous Apex and Lightning Component(Lightning Out) it's working fine for some times, and getting the following exception some other times

> 20:12:12.801 Exception during handling of messages Unrecognized advice action handshake

i have gone through so many questions and realized it is a known issue, it will be solved if we use [empAPI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:empApi/documentation) . But the problem here is empAPI don't support in lightningout. So how can i resolve this?

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page title="MAL and NAL update" >
<apex:includeLightning />
<div style="padding-bottom:3px;" id="MalandNal" />
<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:MALandNALBulkUpdateApp", function() {
      $Lightning.createComponent("c:MALandNALBulkUpdate",
      { },
      "MalandNal",
      function(cmp) {
        // do some stuff
      });
    });
</script>
```

**Component which subscribes the event**

```
<aura:component Controller="MALandNALBulkUpdateController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">

<aura:attribute access="public" name="successMessageList" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute access="public" name="errorMessageList" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute access="public" name="messageList" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute access="public" name="filteredList" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute access="public" name="fileName" type="String" default="No File Selected.." />
<aura:attribute access="public" name="user" type="user"/>

<aura:handler event="aura:waiting" action="{!c.showSpinner}"/>
<aura:handler event="aura:doneWaiting" action="{!c.hideSpinner}"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<!--create a component attributs -->
<aura:attribute name="Spinner" type="boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:handler event="aura:doneRendering" action="{!c.done}" />

<!--Include StreamingApiHandler child component and pass channel name to subscribe
 once the event is fired, it will handled in handleMessage controller method -->

<c:StreamingApiHandler channelName="/event/Notification__e" onStreamEvent="{!c.handleMessage}" />
```

**handleMessage on JAVASCript controller**

```
handleMessage : function(component, event, helper) {
    const param = event.getParam('message');
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(param));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(param.payload));
    var messageList=component.get("v.messageList");
    messageList.push(param.payload);
    component.set("v.messageList",messageList);
    component.set("v.filteredList",messageList);
    //console.log(`Account "${param.sobject.Name}" with Id ${param.sobject.Id} is ${param.event.type}!!`);
}
```

**Batch Class which publishesh the events**

```
global class MALNALBatchClass implements database.Batchable<String> {
public list<String> fileRows;
public String organization;
global MALNALBatchClass(List<String> fileRows,String organization){
    this.fileRows=fileRows;
    this.organization=organization;
}

global Iterable<String> start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    return fileRows;
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bC, List<String> fileRows){
    MALandNALBulkUpdateController malAndNAL=new MALandNALBulkUpdateController();
    malAndNAL.updateAccounts(fileRows,malAndNAL,organization);
    system.debug(malAndNAL.messageList);
    //publish event 
    Notification__e notify = new Notification__e(Id__c=malAndNAL.messageList[0].id,is_Success__c=malAndNAL.messageList[0].isSuccess,
                                                 Message__c=malAndNAL.messageList[0].message); 
    Database.SaveResult result = EventBus.publish(notify);
}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext info){
}
```

}

Comment: can you add relevant code?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, it's a huge code, i have added some part of the code which relevant to this issue. Please  have a look.

Comment: that lightning:out component in VF, why not use VF and cometD library?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/code_sample_combined_pushtopic_intro.htm#code_sample_vfp_pushtopic_intro

Comment: In near future we may move to lightning Experience, currently it is exposed as a VF tab. When we move to LEX, we can directly use the same component.